# How Should I point My DNS Records to My own Website

Tags: dns, domain, web-development, domain-name

I have recently purchased a domain name from ZnetLive.com

I want to know, what can I do with my domain to make it point towards my website?

To be precise:

**

> I have a wordpress account. I want that Whenever a user types
>   nameOfMyWebsite.com he is redirected to my Wordpress Website.

**

Note: I am using a free wordpress account.
Please Help!
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

According to the page https://en.support.wordpress.com/map-existing-domain/, you can map your domain to your free wordpress account by adding DNS records to your configuration at ZnetLive.com.

To do so, you should add `NS` records to your domain on the registrar website, targetting the WordPress name servers (NS1.WORDPRESS.COM, NS2.WORDPRESS.COM and NS3.WORDPRESS.COM) and update your website configuration as mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

Park the domain name you want to use with your Blogger account on our parked nameservers. For more information, see Parking Your Domain Name.
Edit the www CNAME record for the domain name you want to use with your Blogger account. This update tells the Web browser to open your Blogger blog when visitors enter your [domain name's URL](http://www.entcengg.com) in the browser address bar.
Next, you'll need to create separate A records for each of the IPs listed in step 9 of this Google help article.

For instructions on configuring separate A records, please visit Manage DNS for Your Domain Names under the segment Adding or Editing A Records. Each of the records should have the host @
Using instructions from the same help article listed above, configure your Blogger account to use your domain name.